# How do I dynamically update the JSON-LD Script for the Schema

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have the following script, my question is given after the script.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
 {
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Bat,

  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.9",
    "ratingCount": "77"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "lowPrice": "5.76",
    "highPrice": "8",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  }
}
```

I want update `ratingValue` and `ratingCount`

Comment: What is your issue ? Can you show your code please ?

Comment: I want update ratingValue and ratingCount in schema dynamically

Comment: In PHP, JS ? Please, show us your current code. Also, the given is not a valid JSON (`"Bat`).

Comment: I want to show in HTML using JS and PHP.
You just take any demo JSON but rating need to store in database and data get from database using PHP and JS and fetch in HTML file



Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to generate the whole script tag dynamically. Note that I only add the generated json to the body in order to visually present what is added to the head. You can add structured data to the body though.

```js
const product = {
  "name": "MyProduct",
  "ratingValue": "4.9",
  "ratingCount": "77",
  "lowPrice": "5.76",
  "highPrice": "8"
}

const structuredData = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Bat",

  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": product.ratingValue,
    "ratingCount": product.ratingCount
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "lowPrice": product.lowPrice,
    "highPrice": product.highPrice,
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  }
}

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'application/ld+json');
script.textContent = JSON.stringify(structuredData);
document.head.appendChild(script);

const show = document.getElementById('show');
show.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(structuredData);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- your content here... -->
  <div id="show"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can find some more documentation to the topic here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/generate-structured-data-with-javascript